How to digitally sign a PDF using External Container
I am using .net 8 along with following packages
itext.bouncy-castle-adapter version-8.0.5
itext7 version-8.0.5
I think the issue lies somewhere in the implementation of IExternalSignatureContainer.
If I do it by first reserving the space for the signature and later use SignDeferred method of PdfSigner then it works as I have attached the code for it but that is not the flow I want to have.
Following is my code
public class Client
{
    private readonly IOptionsMonitor<PrivateKeySettings> _privateKeySettingsMonitor;

    public Client(
        IOptionsMonitor<PrivateKeySettings> privateKeySettingsMonitor,
        IOptionsMonitor<CertificatePathSettings> certificatePathSettings
        )
    {
        _privateKeySettingsMonitor = privateKeySettingsMonitor;
    }
    public void SignDocument(Stream pdfStream, Stream signatureImageStream, float x, float y, float width, float height)
    {
        // Read the PDF document into a byte array
        using (MemoryStream pdfMemoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            pdfStream.CopyTo(pdfMemoryStream);
            byte[] pdfBytes = pdfMemoryStream.ToArray();

            // Hash the PDF document
            byte[] documentHash = HashDocument(pdfBytes);

            // Send the hash to the server and receive the signed hash
            byte[] signedHash = SendHashToServer(documentHash);

            // Finalize the document by applying the signature
            var signerInfo = new SignerInfo("1", "123@abc.com", "MyComp", "Some text", "04432212345", "USA NY", "NewYork", "USA");
            pdfMemoryStream.Position = 0;
            ApplySignatureToPdf(pdfMemoryStream, signatureImageStream, signerInfo, signedHash, "sig", "Test", "Location", x, y, width, height);
        }
    }

    private byte[] HashDocument(byte[] documentBytes)
    {
        using (SHA256 sha256 = SHA256.Create())
        {
            return sha256.ComputeHash(documentBytes);
        }
    }

    private byte[] SendHashToServer(byte[] hash)
    {
        // Simulated server-side signing for demonstration purposes
        return GetSignedHash(hash);
    }
    // Helper to generate custom signature text with all required fields
    private static string GenerateCustomSignatureText(SignerInfo signerInfo)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        AppendIfNotEmpty(sb, "Signed by: ", signerInfo.Name);
        AppendIfNotEmpty(sb, "Some Name: ", signerInfo.NameAr);
        AppendIfNotEmpty(sb, "Version: ", signerInfo.Version);
        AppendIfNotEmpty(sb, "Mobile: ", signerInfo.Mobile);
        AppendIfNotEmpty(sb, "Email: ", signerInfo.Email);
        AppendIfNotEmpty(sb, "Address: ", signerInfo.Address);
        AppendIfNotEmpty(sb, "Country: ", signerInfo.Country);
        sb.AppendLine($"Date: {DateTime.Now:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}");

        return sb.ToString();
    }
    private static void AppendIfNotEmpty(StringBuilder sb, string label, string value)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value))
        {
            sb.AppendLine($"{label}{value}");
        }
    }
    private void ApplySignatureToPdf(Stream pdfStream, Stream signatureImageStream, SignerInfo signerInfo, byte[] signedHash, string fieldName, string reason, string location, float x, float y, float width, float height)
    {
        using (PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(pdfStream))
        using (MemoryStream outputStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            PdfSigner signer = new PdfSigner(reader, outputStream, new StampingProperties());

            // Create the signature appearance
            Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(x, y, width, height);
            signer.SetFieldName(fieldName);
            signer.SetReason(reason);
            signer.SetLocation(location);
            signer.SetPageRect(rect);
            signer.SetPageNumber(1);

            string customText = GenerateCustomSignatureText(signerInfo);

            // Optional: Set signature image if provided
            SignatureFieldAppearance sigapp = new SignatureFieldAppearance(fieldName).SetContent(customText);

            // Conditionally add the image if the stream is not null or empty
            if (signatureImageStream != null && signatureImageStream.Length > 0)
            {
                ImageData imageData = ImageDataFactory.Create(FileProcessor.ReadStreamToByteArray(signatureImageStream));
                sigapp.SetContent(customText, imageData);  // Update with image if available
            }

            signer.SetSignatureAppearance(sigapp);

            // Sign the document with the signed hash
            IExternalSignatureContainer external = new MyExternalSignatureContainerLast(signedHash);
            signer.SignExternalContainer(external, 8192);

            // Save the signed document
            string DEST = "C:\\Users\\XYZ\\Documents\\Last_Try.pdf";

            File.WriteAllBytes(DEST, outputStream.ToArray());
        }
    }
    private X509Certificate2[] LoadCertificateChain(string pfxPath, string pfxPassword)
    {
        X509Certificate2Collection certificateCollection = new X509Certificate2Collection();
        certificateCollection.Import(pfxPath, pfxPassword, X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet);

        X509Certificate2[] certificateChain = new X509Certificate2[certificateCollection.Count];
        certificateCollection.CopyTo(certificateChain, 0);

        return certificateChain;
    }

    #region SERVER Side
    public byte[] GetSignedHash(byte[] documentHash)
    {
        string PFX_PATH = _privateKeySettingsMonitor.CurrentValue.PfxPath; // PFX file path
        string PFX_PASSWORD = _privateKeySettingsMonitor.CurrentValue.PfxPassword; // PFX password

        X509Certificate2 certificate = new X509Certificate2(PFX_PATH, PFX_PASSWORD, X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet);

        // Create a chain policy
        X509Chain chain = new X509Chain();
        chain.Build(certificate); // This builds the chain

        // Load the certificate from the PFX file
        using RSA rsa = certificate.GetRSAPrivateKey();

        // Sign the hash
        byte[] signedHash = rsa.SignHash(documentHash, HashAlgorithmName.SHA256, RSASignaturePadding.Pkcs1);
        List<X509Certificate2> chainCertificates = chain.ChainElements.Cast<X509ChainElement>().Select(e => e.Certificate).ToList();

        return signedHash;
    }
    #endregion
}

And this is where I think the issue is
class MyExternalSignatureContainerLast : IExternalSignatureContainer
{
    private readonly byte[] signedHash;

    public MyExternalSignatureContainerLast(byte[] signedHash)
    {
        this.signedHash = signedHash;
    }

    public byte[] Sign(Stream inputStream)
    {
        return signedHash; // Return the signed hash from the server
    }

    public void ModifySigningDictionary(PdfDictionary signDic)
    {
        // Optional: Modify the signing dictionary if needed
    }
}

I tried following and it works but this is not how I want it due to some constraints.
public byte[] EmptySignature(Stream pdfStream, Stream signatureImageStream, SignerInfo signerInfo, string fieldname, float x, float y, float width, float height)
{
    using (MemoryStream tempStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(pdfStream);
        PdfSigner signer = new PdfSigner(reader, tempStream, new StampingProperties());

        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(x, y, width, height);
        signer.SetFieldName(fieldname);
        signer.SetReason("Testing Signature");
        signer.SetLocation("Newyork");
        signer.SetContact(signerInfo.Name);
        signer.SetPageRect(rect);
        signer.SetPageNumber(1);
        signer.SetSignatureCreator("TestSDK");

        string customText = GenerateCustomSignatureText(signerInfo);

        SignatureFieldAppearance sigapp = new SignatureFieldAppearance(fieldname).SetContent(customText);

        // Conditionally add the image if the stream is not null or empty
        if (signatureImageStream != null && signatureImageStream.Length > 0)
        {
            ImageData imageData = ImageDataFactory.Create(FileProcessor.ReadStreamToByteArray(signatureImageStream));
            sigapp.SetContent(customText, imageData);  // Update with image if available
        }

        signer.SetSignatureAppearance(sigapp);

        IExternalSignatureContainer external = new ExternalBlankSignatureContainer(PdfName.Adobe_PPKLite, PdfName.Adbe_pkcs7_detached);

        // Sign the document
        signer.SignExternalContainer(external, 8192);

        // Return the byte array of the signed PDF
        return tempStream.ToArray();
    }
}

  public void CreateSignature(byte[] signedPdfBytes, string dest, string fieldName, PrivateKeySignature privateKeySignature, IX509Certificate[] chain)
  {
      using (MemoryStream inputStream = new MemoryStream(signedPdfBytes))
      using (FileStream os = new FileStream(dest, FileMode.Create))
      {
          PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(inputStream);
          PdfSigner signer = new PdfSigner(reader, os, new StampingProperties());
          //signer.SetOriginalOutputStream(os);
          IExternalSignatureContainer external = new MyExternalSignatureContainer(privateKeySignature, chain);

          PdfSigner.SignDeferred(signer.GetDocument(), fieldName, os, external);
      }
  }

        class MyExternalSignatureContainer : IExternalSignatureContainer
        {
            protected PrivateKeySignature privateKeySignature;
            protected IX509Certificate[] chain;

            public MyExternalSignatureContainer(PrivateKeySignature privateKeySignature, IX509Certificate[] chain)
            {
                this.privateKeySignature = privateKeySignature;
                this.chain = chain;
            }

            public byte[] Sign(Stream inputStream)
            {
                try
                {
                    String digestAlgorithmName = privateKeySignature.GetDigestAlgorithmName();

                    PdfPKCS7 sgn = new PdfPKCS7(null, chain, digestAlgorithmName, false);
                    byte[] hash = DigestAlgorithms.Digest(inputStream, digestAlgorithmName);
                    byte[] sh = sgn.GetAuthenticatedAttributeBytes(hash, PdfSigner.CryptoStandard.CMS,
                        null, null);
                    byte[] extSignature = privateKeySignature.Sign(sh);
                    sgn.SetExternalSignatureValue(extSignature, null, privateKeySignature.GetSignatureAlgorithmName());

                    return sgn.GetEncodedPKCS7(hash, PdfSigner.CryptoStandard.CMS, null,
                        null, null);
                }
                catch (IOException ioe)
                {
                    throw new Exception(ioe.Message);
                }
            }

            public void ModifySigningDictionary(PdfDictionary signDic)
            {
            }
        }


So as mentioned by @mkl I did following
public class CustomExternalSignature : IExternalSignature
{
    private readonly string hashAlgorithm;
    private readonly X509Certificate2 cert;
    public CustomExternalSignature(string hashAlgorithm, X509Certificate2 cert)
    {
        this.hashAlgorithm = hashAlgorithm;
        this.cert = cert;
    }

    public string GetHashAlgorithm() => hashAlgorithm;  // e.g., "SHA-256"

    public string GetEncryptionAlgorithm() => "RSA";  // PFX usually uses RSA
    public string GetDigestAlgorithmName()
    {
        // Return the digest algorithm name used for signing.
        return "SHA-256"; // Use the same algorithm you are using for signing.
    }

    public string GetSignatureAlgorithmName()
    {
        // Return the signature algorithm name used for signing.
        return "SHA256WithRSA"; // Adjust based on your signing algorithm.
    }
    public ISignatureMechanismParams GetSignatureMechanismParameters()
    {
        return null;
    }
    public byte[] Sign(byte[] message)
    {
        return GetSignedHash(message);
    }

    private byte[] GetSignedHash(byte[] message)
    {
        var documentHash = Client.HashDocument(message);
        using RSA? rsa = cert.GetRSAPrivateKey();

        // Sign the hash
        byte[] signedHash = rsa?.SignHash(documentHash, HashAlgorithmName.SHA256, RSASignaturePadding.Pkcs1) ?? new byte[0];

        return signedHash;
    }
}

Question is this the correct way of doing it?
I need to move "GetSignedHash" method code to a signing service.
Is this okay? Or signing service should be doing something different?
Following is the complete implementation(changed from two step process to one step)
    private void ApplySignatureToPdf(Stream pdfStream, Stream signatureImageStream, SignerInfo signerInfo,/* byte[] signedHash,*/ string fieldName, string reason, string location, float x, float y, float width, float height)
    {
        using (PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(pdfStream))
        using (MemoryStream outputStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            PdfSigner signer = new PdfSigner(reader, outputStream, new StampingProperties());

            // Create the signature appearance
            Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(x, y, width, height);
            signer.SetFieldName(fieldName);
            signer.SetReason(reason);
            signer.SetLocation(location);
            signer.SetPageRect(rect);
            signer.SetPageNumber(1);

            string customText = GenerateCustomSignatureText(signerInfo);

            // Optional: Set signature image if provided
            SignatureFieldAppearance sigapp = new SignatureFieldAppearance(fieldName).SetContent(customText);

            // Conditionally add the image if the stream is not null or empty
            if (signatureImageStream != null && signatureImageStream.Length > 0)
            {
                ImageData imageData = ImageDataFactory.Create(FileProcessor.ReadStreamToByteArray(signatureImageStream));
                sigapp.SetContent(customText, imageData);  // Update with image if available
            }
            signer.SetSignatureAppearance(sigapp);

            string PFX_PATH = _privateKeySettingsMonitor.CurrentValue.PfxPath; // PFX file path
            string PFX_PASSWORD = _privateKeySettingsMonitor.CurrentValue.PfxPassword; // PFX password

            ICipherParameters privateKey = LoadPrivateKey(PFX_PATH, PFX_PASSWORD);
            X509Certificate2 certificate = new X509Certificate2(PFX_PATH, PFX_PASSWORD, X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet);

            IExternalSignature externalSignature = new CustomExternalSignature("SHA-256", certificate);


            var chain = GetCertificateChain(PFX_PATH!, PFX_PASSWORD.ToCharArray());

            signer.SignDetached(externalSignature, chain, null, null, null, 0, PdfSigner.CryptoStandard.CMS);

            // Save the signed document
            string DEST = "C:\\Users\\XYZ\\Documents\\Last_Try.pdf";

            File.WriteAllBytes(DEST, outputStream.ToArray());
        }
    }



Well, in your upper code you hash the original PDF. That's not how integrated signatures work. The lower code looks ok at first glance but unnecessarily complicated - if you have code that returns a naked signature value (and not a full-fledged signature container), you'd usually use an IExternalSignature< not an IExternalSignatureContsiner. Also you mention constraints. What are they?

Constraints like I can't use private key signature to sign the hash inside of MyExternalSignatureContainer.
I want to first hash the document and then create the signature by hashing using private key in a pfx file.
So you are saying I need to use the externalSignature instead of externalsignaturecontainer? If yes is there any difference in code for externalSignature  I believe it should be

I googled and found out that I need to use Full-fledged Signature Container as I have to to make sure that the signature is verifiable by PDF readers like Adobe Acrobat and also it should hold the signature metadata and references.
As per chatgpt Naked Signature value won't be verifiable by PDF readers (then what is the point of adding this signature if adobe can't tell if the signature is valid or not)

Well, chatgpt can be misleading. Yes, a CMS container has to be embedded into the PDF for interoperable signatures (well, there is one variant that works with a naked signature but that is deprecated in PDF-2) but many signing frameworks (like iText's signing API) create the CMS container for you if you just provide the signer certificate and the algorithm your signature uses, and create a naked signature for a value the framework provides. In case of iText the signing methods using an IExternalSignature work just that way.

"I want to first hash the document and then create the signature by hashing using private key in a pfx file." - as mentioned above, integrated signing does not use the hash of the original PDF. "So you are saying I need to use the externalSignature instead of externalsignaturecontainer?" - you don't need to, it's merely simpler. "If yes is there any difference in code for externalSignature I believe it should be" - Yes, PdfSigner has different methods for the different signing interfaces.

@mkl I have updated the question with implementation of IExternalSignature

At first glance it looks ok. Have you run it? Does it work?

@mkl yes I did but i am not sure it if its the right way of doing it.
I aim to do "Signing a document on the client using a signature created on the server"
Which is mentioned in the following itext7 link
https://kb.itextpdf.com/itext/digital-signatures-chapter-4#Digitalsignatures-chapter4-c4_07_clientserversigning

'I aim to do "Signing a document on the client using a signature created on the server"' - What kind of server? How are you going to access that server? You will have to change your CustomExternalSignature.Sign method to sign the given data (byte[] message) by your server and return the naked signature. And you'll have to change your GetCertificateChain method to retrieve the matching certificate chain.
